# PartialFunction accepting Unit

Tags: scala, types

Here's the simple example:

```
val f: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = (_: Any) match {
  case Val(s) => println("Val" + s)
  case Sup(l) => println("Sup" + l)
  case t : Unit => println("Unit")
}
f()  //prints Unit
```

and it works fine. But if I replace the function defenition with this:

```
val f: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = (_: Any) match {
  case Val(s) => println("Val" + s)
  case Sup(l) => println("Sup" + l)
  case Unit => println("Unit")
}
f(Unit) //prints Unit
f() //throws scala.MatchError
```

it works different.

I don't understand this behavior. How is it ever possible to pass a ***Type*** as a function parameter? To me (I came from Java) it seems strange.

Comment: You're not passing a type, but the companion object `Unit` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Unit$).

Answer (score 3):

In example 1, you're matching a value of type `Unit`. There is only one value of this type: `()`, see [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit). I'm not quite sure why it is possible to write `f()` instead of `f(())`, maybe this is just syntactic sugar.

In example 2, you're matching the object [`Unit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit$). This case is rather unusual and probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

1.`f()` scala compiler will automatically expand it to `f((): Unit)`,
    you can verify it by and [SI-9278](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9278):

```
case t : Unit => println("Unit: " + t)
```

you can think `(): Unit` is a empty tuple variable. so when `f()` to `case Unit`, it will throw `MatchError`, it's caused by you are passing a variable.

2.as @devkat said, `Unit` is an object:

```
object Unit extends AnyValCompanion {
  def box(x: Unit): scala.runtime.BoxedUnit = scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
  def unbox(x: java.lang.Object): Unit = ()]
  override def toString = "object scala.Unit"
}
```

3.`f(Unit)` means pass an `Unit` object to `pattern match`. so `case Unit` it matches.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others: f () in this case, is actually just infix notation for f( () ) which means in the f() examples we're passing in 1 parameter, which is () (i.e. we're not passing in no parameters)

As for the 2 function definitions:

- The first says: if t instanceOf Unit (class) match
- The second says: if t == Unit (constant) match

scala.Unit is both an abstract class AND an object singleton.  In the first function, it is testing against the abstract class.  In the second function it's testing the constant / singleton object.

If we try this:

```
println( ().isInstanceOf[Unit]) // true
println( () == scala.Unit) //false
println( () == scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT) //true
println( scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT.isInstanceOf[Unit]) //true
println( scala.Unit.isInstanceOf[Unit]) //false
```

the output is:

```
true
false
true
true
false
```

which shows that

- scala.Unit *object* is not actually the same thing as ().
- scala.Unit *object* does not even inherit from the *abstract class* Unit.
- () does inherit from the *abstract class* Unit.

Based on this knowledge, in the 2nd function you are passing in (), which is actually scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT.  The pattern match is then trying to match against the scala.Unit object.  They are not the same objects, so it fails.

In the first function, if you had done this f(Unit) - it would throw a MatchError.  Reason being Unit (object) is not an instance of Unit (abstract class).  () is an instance of Unit (abstract class), so it works.